# Python Google App Engine: Call specific method from yaml file?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, yaml

I am new to database programming with Google App Engine and am programming in Python. I was wondering if I am allowed to have one Python file with several request handler classes, each of which has get and post methods. I know that the yaml file allows me to specify which scripts are run with specific urls, like the example below:

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.py
```

How would I tell it to run a specific method that is in one of the classes in the .py file? Is that even possible/allowed? Do I need to separate the different request handler classes into different python files? My understanding of databases is rather shallow at the moment, so I could be making no sense.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was wondering if I am allowed to
>   have one Python file with several
>   request handler classes, each of which
>   has get and post methods.

Sure!  That `app.yaml` just transfers control to `helloworld.py`, which will run the `main` function defined in that file -- and that function typically sets up a WSGI app which dispatches appropriately, depending on the URL, to the right handler class.  For example, look at the sample code [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/handlingforms.html), very early on in the tutorial:

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                                     [('/', MainPage),
                                      ('/sign', Guestbook)],
                                     debug=True)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I'm not copying the `import` statements and class definitions, because they don't matter: this is an example of how a single `.py` file dispatches to various handler classes (two in this case).

This doesn't mean the yaml file lets you call any method whatsoever, of course: rather, it hands control to a `.py` file, whose `main` is responsible for all that follows (and e.g. with the `webapp` mini-framework that comes with App Engine, it will always be `get` or `post` method [[or `put`, `delete`, ..., etc, if you also support those -- few do unless they're being especially RESTful;-)]] being called depending on the exact HTTP method and URL in the incoming request.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough and helpful answer! I think I'm slowly starting to get a grip of databases and all. Very interesting stuff :)

Comment: By the way, what does debug=True do?

Comment: @Ayanonagon, you're welcome!  `debug=True` means to show the tracebacks from exceptions (if any) on the visiting browser, otherwise by default only a very opaque "internal server error" (HTTP status 500) is given.